# Insert object inside an array

Tags: javascript

I need to save some data in an array. But these objects are dynamically inserted from the user input so the input is done by iterating.

```
    data2 = {};

    for(j=0;j<ebs_no;j++){
        for(k=0;k<$('[name=snap_no'+j+']').val();k++){
            data2[i].snapshot.push({
                duration : $('name=duration'+j+k).val(),
                every : $('name=every'+j+k).val(),
                keep : $('name=keep'+j+k).val()
            });
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error

> Cannot read property '`snapshot`' of undefined

and app is crashing down.

the end out put should something like this

```
   { 
    ebs:[{duration : String,
                every : Number,
                keep : Number
         }]
   }
```

Comment: `data2 = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < ebs_no; j++) {
        // Define empty array here
        data2[j].snapshot = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < $('[name=snap_no' + j + ']').val(); k++) {
            data2[j].snapshot.push({
                duration: $('name=duration' + j + k).val(),
                every: $('name=every' + j + k).val(),
                keep: $('name=keep' + j + k).val()
            });
        }
    }`

Comment: There's no JSON at all in the question. You're just dealing with **JavaScript** objects and arrays. JSON is a *textual* notation: If you're writing JavaScript code, and not dealing with strings, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: What should the end result look like?

Comment: @Tushar OP used `i` not `j` to access `data2`.

Comment: the end product should be something like this { ebs:[{duration : String, every : Number, keep : Number }] }

Comment: What if you do `data2[i].snapshot = []` before `push()`?

Comment: @Tushar is there any more optimized way to do this task. By the way thanks.

Comment: @SaprativeJana `data2 = {};
for (var j = 0; j < ebs_no; j++) {
    data2[j].snapshot = [];

    var limit = $('[name=snap_no' + j + ']').val();
    for (var k = 0; k < limit; k++) {
        data2[j].snapshot.push({
            duration: $('name=duration' + j + k).val(),
            every: $('name=every' + j + k).val(),
            keep: $('name=keep' + j + k).val()
        });
    }
}`

Comment: @Tushar i am still having that error

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you:

```
var data2 = [];
var ebs_no = 20;

for(var j = 0; j < ebs_no; j++){

    data2[j] = { snapshot: [] };

    for(var k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        data2[j].snapshot.push({
            duration : 'testduration',
            every : 'testevery',
            keep : 'testkeep'
        });
    }
}
```